Looking for problems requiring directed cycle covers without short cycles
The problem  of  Computing Cycle Covers without Short Cycles is NP complete for the case of deciding the existence of a vertex cover with vertex-disjoint, directed cycles with at least 3 vertices.
An alternative interpretation is as square assignment problem in which assigning worker $i$ to job $j$ rules out assigning worker $j$ to job $i$.
Question:

what are examples of "interesting"/"important" problems that require finding vertex-covers with directed cycles with at least 3 vertices?
I would be especially interested in "real life" examples.

